# Access pouchdb-server on heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, network-programming, heroku-cli

I git cloned [pouchdb-server](https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb-server) and followed [this tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#run-the-app-locally).

I set up the [procfile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile) like this: `web: pouchdb-server --port 5984`

When I run `heroku local web` it works fine, but when I run `heroku open` it does not. I keep getting the error `at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=myhost.herokuapp.com request_id=someidnumber fwd="myglobalip" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https`

I'm aware I need to set up the `index.js` like in the tutorial, but I don't know how.

What I want to do is when I access `https://myhost.herokuapp.com/` it's as if I was accessing the pouchdb server. So any request that I make to that address it's like I'm making to pouchdb server. And when I type `https://myhost.herokuapp.com/_utils` I access the Fauxton web interface.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out there's an issue on github asking the exact same thing with the solution in the comments: https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb-server/issues/124